# Hide Word Mobile Menu in Android Webview

Tags: android, wordpress, webview

I tried to get a Mobile Android app of my website https://www.mein-angelschein.de.

I bought a WebView Template on envato: [Link](https://codecanyon.net/item/universal-android-webview-app/8431507)

The app runs smoothly, but how can I hide my mobile menu on the upper right side when the page is shown in the Webview? The app has its own menu with links in, so I don't need the mobile menu. I use Wordpress with the THE7-theme.

Any Suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in Android Studio and navigate it to app > res > menu. There you will be shown a list of XML files. one among the list contains the menu to the page that you mentioned. Open the file and add `android:visible="false"` to your XML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Idea, but i don't want to hide the Menu of the Webview Template, i want to hide the menu that comes from the wordpress mobile page. this menu is shown when you use a mobile browser without the app. but in the app this menu shall be invisible because the app has its own menu!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a unique custom user agent string in the webview of your android app.

```
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.your_webView_id);
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("your_custom_user_agent_string_name");
```

2. Hide the menu based on the user agent string of the visitor of your website. If user agent string equals to "your_custom_user_agent_string_name", don't show the menu, else show it.